# python selenium webdriver : click 'read more'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

[inspect > elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNkbP.jpg)

for scarping website(TripAdvisor), i wanted to click 'read more' by using selenium webdriver and scraping full reviews. I tried 5 scripts as below but anything didn't work. Please let me know the right answer

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("dlJyA")[0].click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dlJyA']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'eljVo _S Z')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dlJyA']/span[@class='eljVo _S Z')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('eIVRK').click()
```

and the CSS was of website was

```
<div class="eIVRK" style="line-height: 20px;">  <div class="dlJyA" data-test-target="expand-review">   <span class="eljVo _S Z">Read more</span>   <span class="ui_icon caret-down zedZf">   </span>  </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wait for the page to load first, using `implicitly_wait`

```
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
```

Code:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('eIVRK').click()
```

Comment: Thank you! but I got error with your code :  Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="eIVRK" style="line-height: 20px;">...</div> is not clickable at point (80, 509). Other element would receive the click: <div class="onetrust-pc-dark-filter ot-fade-in" style="z-index:2147483645;"></div>

Comment: @PCho Try other ID's.

Comment: Yes you can use implicitly_wait. ;)